# Can Office 365 and Google Apps coexist in an enterprise?

Tags: g-suite, microsoft-office-365

Can a corporation adopt both technologies and allow the employee, or teams choose which would be best for them. For example, could I choose to use GApps, yet my colleague in another office or country use Microsoft Office 365?

Comment: I can't figure out the value of doing this, but I can imagine the horror stories from helpdesk and support you'll be getting for the complexity of the setup you'll end up with :), I'd avoid this at all costs.

Comment: Well, I'm thinking of a company with tech saavy people. Some of which prefer Microsoft Office. Others who prefer GApps. The value is one of having the end users having an experience they prefer, rather than being dictated to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the services you're targeting, and if the user identity will be created on both systems or only one of them, I'll go with the assumption that the identity will be created only once. Here are some short answers:

**From Microsoft side:**

- Mail: most probably yes.
- Calendar: nope.
- Address book: nope.
- Skype for business: nope.
- SharePoint for teams: nope.

**From Google Side:**

- Mail: most probably yes.
- Calendar: nope.
- Address book: nope.
- Gtalk (or whatever it is now): nope.
- Google Drive for teams (or whatever it is now): nope.

You'll eventually end up managing two different systems that each has its own users with no way for them to interact except by email. And as I said in the comments, it'll be a nightmare to manage for IT departments, I would highly recommend to not give this kind of power to end users to decide on, they don't know how to handle it or the impact of their decisions.

Comment: Good points. I was definitely envisaging that each user's identity would be on only the system in which they chose to use. And as there's no interoperability for shared calendars and addresses between the two, it **wouldn't** be very useful. Thanks for taking the time to consider it a bit more, @noor :-)