# Use Google apps (G-suite) and Office 365 in one doman

Tags: email, mx-record, g-suite, microsoft-office-365, sametime

I have a domain midominio.com and I use google apps to manage and use email. Now I have to move to Microsoft Office 365. The question is if can have the google mail and the microsoft mail with domain midominio.com at the same time. I know with the mx records can do that, but the main issue is: this will work if I have a email info@midominio.com in google apps, but is not setup in microsoft or have a email store@midominio in microsoft, but not setup in google apps.

It is possible to make it work?

Comment: related: http://serverfault.com/questions/797322/can-office-365-and-google-apps-coexist-in-an-enterprise?rq=1   Short answer is that mail can coexist, but you're going to be doing a lot of forwarding between organizations.  This is acceptable as a migration strategy, but not for long-term usage.